# Replace post's "the_content" with ACF value

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, the-content

I try to replace post's `the_content` with value from ACF field `article_text`. I managed to achieve it with following method:

```
  $postid = get_queried_object_id();

  $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $postid,
      'post_content' => get_field('article_text'),
  );

  wp_update_post( $my_post );

  the_content();
```

But I have a small issue with it: when I create post, `the_content` doesn't automatically gets the value from ACF `article_text`. I have to refresh the browser couple times in order to see that change. When I preview the post without publishing, I cannot see `the_content` at all.

My question - is there a more efficient way to do it to see the content straight away?

The reason why I want to display `the_content` instead of `article_text` is because of several not-ACF-friendly plugins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of updating the post's content, you can filter it using the `the_content` filter.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse241388_use_acf_field' );
function wpse241388_use_acf_field( $content ) {
    return get_field( 'article_text' );
}
```

### Update

To apply to only your `article` post type:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse241388_use_acf_field' );
function wpse241388_use_acf_field( $content ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'article' ) ) {
        $content = get_field( 'article_text' );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

### References

- [`the_content` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/)
- [`is_singular()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/)

Comment: Actually I have one more question. If I want to apply it only to specific post type `article`. How would you recommend to modify your code?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Use one or the other, not both, of the snippets.

Comment: Doing it this way doesn't allow for the use of <!--next page-->. Any way around this?